# Image not being captured by default camera started using intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android app development and learning it. I have a button which on click starts the openCamera() function. My aim is to capture the image and display it. Currently the button click opens the default camera but the image is not being captured, just a dark image is being displayed. on clicking the capture button nothing happens. Tried on genymotion emulator with both front and back camera enabled to webcam. Here is the code:

```
public void openCamera(View view)
{

    if(view.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {
        messageBox("Opening Camera");
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageuri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
}
public void messageBox(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri selectedImage = imageuri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage,null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try
                {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,selectedImage);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(this,selectedImage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Camera",e.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: The code seems about right. Did you try it on a real device?